# Django Rest Framework: Should I use URL Slugs or query parameters to list items of specific category?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Right now I have a viewset that allows me to:

1. List all the products on: www.example.com/api/products
2. Retrieve the detail information of one product on:
   www.example.com/api/products/5

The problem is that in the mobile application the products will only be visible when you are inside a category and subcategory.

The product model looks something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubcategory, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the product Viewset looks like this:

```
class RoutineViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()   

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return serializers.ProductListSerializer
        else:
            return serializers.ProductDetailSerializer
```

Should I be using a slug or ID in the endpoint to get the items?

```
www.example.com/api/products/category/food/subcategory/snacks
www.example.com/api/products/category/2/subcategory/3
```

Or should I be using query parameters?

```
www.example.com/api/products/?category=2,subcategory=3
```

My instinct tells me that the easiest way would be to use query parameters and overwrite the "get_queryset" method to get different products depending on the query parameters. But I'm not sure if that is the standard way of doing something like this.

Thanks

Comment: Both options are OK and equally used. Just chose which is easier for you

Answer (score 0):

you should define Sub Category @action in your View with detail=True